# Dynamic workflow stage in approval workflow in sharepoint 2010

Tags: workflow, approval

How can I create a workflow in SharePoint 2013 for dynamic approval level. My requirement is I have to create a workflow using SPD2013 or VS 2012. Workflow is associated on **list**. It will be initialized automatically through the code.

It is a simple **approval** + It's approver can send back for rework also.  I have implemented that already but now the requirement has changed. I want to make it the approvers configurable meaning it can have one more approver in approver group then it should work for that also. Client don't want to change workflow each time.

How can I achieve this? Currently I am having only two approval level. In future it would be more. How can I do configuration in that? It should automatically add the approver in workflow based on some condition ?

Comment: Can you provide us with some more details, e.g.: SharePoint on-premises? Online? Is a dev (C# code) solution an option? WF in 2010 or 2013 mode?

Answer (score 0):

Use an approval group. Create a SPD workflow and rather than specify individuals for the approval, specify a SharePoint group.